# Mix preg_match, anchor and offset

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have `$string = "hello world, world!";` and I need match the **first** `world` only, so I have too an *offset*. It start on 6th character. The `preg_match()` have five arguments: string **pattern**, string **subject**, reference array matches, int flags and int **offset**.

My pattern is: `$pattern = "/^world/";`

If I do `preg_match($pattern, $string, $string_match, 0, 6)`, basically I expect that this works, because the "anchor" will check the 6th letter of my string, because I set the offset. **BUT NOT!** It doesn't works. Oh!

**An easy fix** is, instead of I set an offset to `preg_match()` function, I use `substr()` over `$string`, like it: `preg_match($pattern, substr($string, 6), $string_match)`.

Is possible fix my first code to use correctly the anchor with offset with `preg_match()`? Or it is the unique solution?

Comment: `^` means beginning of string, not first occurrence of a pattern. If you want to learn regex, read some docs rather than trying to learn it all piecemeal off of SO.  It will speed you lightyears ahead. That's where I learned the wisdom I just imparted.

Comment: My problem is not get the **first ocurrence of pattern**, but use anchor with offset, way that it can anchor on start of offset, not start of string. (I really not understand why I been negatived)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong anchor; to play nice with offset you need `\G`, the last match position anchor:

```
$string = 'hello world, world!';

var_dump(preg_match('/\Gworld/', $string, $matches, 0, 6)); // int(1)
```

Interestingly, the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.differences.php) states that `\G` is not supported, but it most certainly is [supported](http://3v4l.org/JnMvP) reliably since 4.3.3.